# SAMBA with Active Directory user group permissions

Tags: permissions, samba, active-directory

I have setup SAMBA with Active Directory authentication (Kerberos & nsswitch etc.) on a Ubuntu box and am trying to correctly set up a shared folder on this Ubuntu box with an Active Directory group of users have read/write/execute permissions (Windows Active Directory domain controller).  Unfortunately, my users can not see or access the shared folder from any client (Windows, Linux or otherwise).

I am sure it is simply my miss-understanding of the correct configuration.

I have Active Directory users (let's call them `user1`, `user2`, `user3`), within an Active Directory Group (lets call it `group1`). They are also, by default, a member of the 'domain users' group.

On Ubuntu, the commands `wbinfo -u` & `wbinfo -g` as well as `getent passwd` & `getent group` can all see the users and groups in question from Active Directory. As expected.

I have a folder on Ubuntu that I created along these lines:

```
mkdir -p /sharing/folder1
chmod -R 0770 /sharing/
chgrp -R "Domain Users" /sharing/
```

and within `smb.conf`:

```
[Share]
    comment = Folder to share
    path = /sharing/folder1/
    valid users = "@DOMAINNAME\domain users"
    force group = "Domain Users"
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    force create mode = 0660
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0770
    access based share enum = yes
    hide unreadable = yes
```

This works, BUT for any and all Active Directory users.
I DON'T want that, I only want the users fro the `group1` in Active Directory to have access to the share and its content.

So, if I try this:

folder on Ubuntu that I created along these lines:

```
mkdir -p /sharing/folder1
chmod -R 0770 /sharing/
chgrp -R "group1" /sharing/
```

and within `smb.conf`:

```
[Share]
    comment = Folder to share
    path = /sharing/folder1/
    valid users = "@DOMAINNAME\group1"
    force group = "group1"
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    force create mode = 0660
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0770
    access based share enum = yes
    hide unreadable = yes
```

This does NOT work for any user.
What am I doing wrong?  What's the difference?

Equally, If I use an individual user, I get hit and miss results.
I am also unable to use a local Ubuntu User it seems.
Note: I need to use a group as the users may come and go over time.

Any support appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, that post didn't format too well.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue?  I'm experiencing similar, wherein I followed [this tutorial](https://samba.ninja/2021/02/freebsd-12-samba-active-directory-member-server/) and samba pulls in AD users+groups, but sticks all users in the `Domain Users` group with no other groups having members.